# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine . Microsoft Office 365

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have problem with Microsoft Office 365 and Microsoft Access database engine. I used Microsoft Office 2016 with Microsoft Access database engine 2010 Redistributable which works fine, but yesterday i switched to Office 365 and i get error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'
I read some microsoft docs and another web sides witchexplains this problem, but nothing work to me.

Now I have installed Microsoft Access database engine 2010 Redistributable 64bit and Microsoft Access database engine 2016 64bit

I would like to point out my office 365 Bussines is 64bit, Windows 10 is 64 bit and visual studio 2019 is 64 bit

Did anyone know, what i have to do?

Comment: *visual studio 2019 is 64 bit*: you mean your application. What is the Target CPU of your app set to? Did you deselect the `Prefer 32-bit` option? What ACE Provider are you currently using? Did you uninstall the 32bit Provider? Are you using Visual Studio's tools to build your application, or are you doing everything in code?

Comment: You should also specify what kind of installation of Office 365 you have and the .Net version in use.

Comment: Target CPU is set to Any CPU. I am using ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider and I uninstalled 32bit provider. No i am not using Visual studio tools iam doing everthing in code. Why i would deselect option Prefer 32-bit?

Comment: Otherwise your application actually runs as a 32bit Process. If the 32bit version of the Provider is not available anymore (*I uninstalled 32bit provider*) , then... -- Also, note that Office 365 may use a sort of *sandbox*, hence the question related to the installation type. -- The ACE Engine installation path also has changed. If not everything went well during the installation of main product, something may not have been updated correctly, so reinstalling the 64bit Engine of the `ACE.16` driver may solve it. -- The .Net version is another thing...

Comment: As for access database engine, I need something extra for them?

Comment: If i need something more than microsoft access database engine 2016

Comment: To create a connection to an Access database, to `SELECT` / `INSERT` / `UPDATE`? Then no. I have not tested ADOX to build / reconfigure a database (e.g., modify / add Indexes, build / remove Tables, build a database from scratch etc.). Works in all previous versions though.

Comment: I'd suggest that your target should actually be x64, not Any CPU.

Comment: @Craig Targeting AnyCPU, you can use both the 32bit and and 64bit versions of the two drivers, even at the same time. If you target a specific CPU, you will always use just one (give it a test drive).